# Is it possible to send SMS using LWUIT?

Tags: lwuit

I want to send SMS using LWUIT. what class should i be looking at? Does LWUIT have a class for sending SMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need LWUIT to send sms. You can design UI using LWUIT and use `MessageConnection` class to send sms. You can have a look at [this](http://www.java.net/node/695825) and [this](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/lists/users/archive/2009-07/message/522) thread.

Comment: I hve already had a look at those pages. But suppose I write that code, will it work for android and black berry? or is it only for J2me?

I want something generic that will work for all the devices

Comment: MessageConnection class is available in J2ME and BlackBerry, but not available in Android. You have to write different code for android. You can follow this tutorial: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android for android.

Comment: exactly!.. i just wanted to know if i can use lwuit for it..so that i don't need to make changes to my code :)